# Do not apply spacing between paragraphs to lists

Tags: microsoft-word, line-spacing

I have a Word document with a custom style for "normal" text.
I recently wanted to change the spacing between paragraphs to make them appear more "separated".

I have done that by changing the "before" spacing of the paragraph style.

The problem is that it also affects the spacing between items of list (numbered or bullets) with this style. It seems that each item of a list is considered as a separate paragraph ?

How do I avoid that behavior and get the same spacing between list items as for between two lines of a paragraph ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Raphael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Styles window. Go to the styling used for lists (back-translated from German: "list paragraph"). Click **Edit**. A new window appears.

[image: Modify Style window]

Click **Format**. Choose **Paragraph**.

[image: Paragraph window]

Change the line-spacing there. This should be it.

If Word has formatted a list of yours using Standard instead of List paragraph (you see that by clicking within the list and seeing which style gets chosen in the Styles window), select the whole list, click on the "Bullets and numbering" button twice. The first time removes all bullets, the second time they come back and the style changes to List paragraph.